# Which are the android native camera supported platforms?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-camera, android-camera2

I am currently working on a camera-based OpenCV app with critical performance requirements

We already have java-based camera implementations - both, [the deprecated HAL 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and also [camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

We use camera1 implementation on platforms < 21 and the Camera 2 implementation on platforms >= 21

These two implementations are already extremely optimized for performance, however, we believe we could still improve by upgrading to the new native ndk camera API (the main improvement would be reducing the overhead of JNI image data transfer to native OpenCV processor)

In Android 7.0 (API 24) release, NDK native camera support was introduced. However, the only NDK documentation available is  [this flat list of C headers](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___camera.html)

Unfortunately, I am currently confused because there is no clear information about native camera platform support

When I looked at the native API I noticed it is very similar to the java camera2 API
This makes me (wishfully) think that the native API should be backward compatible with earlier platforms that support the camera2 java API

I have started an experimental project in an attempt to bust the myth, however, due to generally lacking NDK documentation, progress is slow

I am specially interested if anyone else already attempted to leverage the native camera API and there's a relevant conclusion on this matter that could be shared

On another track, I'm also curious to find out if the camera native API implementation is a reverse JNI binding to the camera2 java API or if it indeed is a lower-level integration. It's also interesting to know if the camera2 java API is a JNI binding to the native camera api?

Comment: NDK r12 *"Added libcamera2 APIs for devices with INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED or above"*. The documented types and functions are supported by the shared library, **libcamera2ndk.so**, which must be available on the target device. The library in NDK (for all ABIs in platforms/android-24/) is only a stub, and you won't gain required functionality if you install it on a device with API 21.

Comment: You can try to build the lib from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/camera/ndk with APP_PLATFORM=android-21. Targeting API < 24, you can dlopen the system libraries it depends upon:     libbinder \
    liblog \
    libgui \
    libutils \
    libandroid_runtime \
    libcamera_client \
    libstagefright_foundation \
    libcutils \
    libcamera_metadata \
    libmediandk

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn for these ideas, I'll give them a try as well!

Comment: @AndreiMarcut: Have you found an anwer to your questions in the meantime? I would be very interested to know more about support for the NDK native camera in versions earlier than API 24 as well.

Answer (score 3):

There's more NDK documentation thank just the C headers; if you click on one of the functions, for example, you can get [reference docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#gab73afbe5075f48570dd830fe9502abbd).

However, I think you're correct in that the compatibility story isn't well-documented.

The short version is that if you call [ACameraManager_getCameraIdList](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#ga7b535801c51172b0308f5613a8c38986) and it returns camera IDs, then you can open those with the NDK API.
If it doesn't return any IDs, then there are no supported cameras on that device.

The longer story is that the NDK API only supports camera devices that have a [hardware level](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#gga49cf3e5a3deefe079ad036a8fac14627a5aaeaef29512926439f4b1994c801eb5) of LIMITED or higher. LEGACY devices are not supported.

---

As an optimization note, how are you passing data through JNI?  While JNI isn't ridiculously fast, it's not that slow, and as long as you're using passing mechanisms that don't copy data (such as direct access to ByteBuffer via [getDirectBufferAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress).

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have already acknowledged the documented API know-how and am aware of the helper support detection functions, however, I am more interested if anyone has hands-on experience or further insights about the new APIs. Indeed the optimization are valid and we already leverage them to the full extent, but also there are other benefits that contribute to the full native implementation migration decision (for example, enhanced security)